# Infinite while loop over two lists - Python

Tags: python, while-loop

I am new in programming and I am trying to implement a function that intersects the element which are presents in two lists.
I want to implement this function with a `while` loop in order to iterate simultaneously over the lists.

Assuming that **the two lists are sorted** I am using this code:

```
def intersection(l1, l2):
    new_ls = []
    i = 0
    j = 0
    while i < len(l1) and j < len(l2):
        if l1[i] == l2[j]:
            new_ls.append(l1[i])
            i += 1
            j += 1
    return new_ls
```

But, even though I increment *i* and *j* at each iteration, it enters in an infinite loop. How could I fix that problem?

Thank you very much for your answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indices must be incremented every time! So try this code:

```
def intersection(l1, l2):
    new_ls = []
    i = 0
    j = 0
    while i < len(l1) and j < len(l2):
        if l1[i] == l2[j]:
            new_ls.append(l1[i])
        i += 1
        j += 1
    return new_ls
```

With your original code, i and j are incremented only if *l1[i] == l2[j]*.

Let's suppose then when i = 1, j = 1 and

- `l1[i]` contains `100`
- `l2[i]` contains `101`

if you write

```
if l1[i] == l2[j]:
    new_ls.append(l1[i])
    i += 1
    j += 1
```

the last two rows can't be executed, because the condition `l1[i] == l2[j]` is *False*.

Answer (score 0):

In the above code, the incrememntation of i and j only happens if the elements in l1 and l2 are the same.

Decrease the indentation of `i += 1` and `j += 1` so that it increments on every loop

```
def intersection(l1, l2):
    new_ls = []
    i = 0
    j = 0
    while i < len(l1) and j < len(l2):
        if l1[i] == l2[j]:
            new_ls.append(l1[i])
        i += 1 # Here
        j += 1 # and here
    return new_ls
```

Answer (score 0):

Learned about the `product` function in the `itertools` module from the python reddit.

Using it your function becomes:

```
from intertools import product

def intersection(l1, l2):
    new_ls = []
    for i1, i2 in product(l1, l2):
        if i1 == i2:
            new_ls.append(i1)
    return new_ls
```

Isn't that nice?

The article was called `The Art of Writing Loops in Python`